# ASCII character for 0 is differenct in vb6.0 compared to c#

Tags: c#, vb6, char, ascii, serial-communication

ASCII character for 0 is differenct in vb6.0 compared to c#. I have converted vb6.0 code to c# where i need to send hex data as characters in port communication.

C# - Comm1.Write('/0').ToString() --> gives char as /0.

VB6.0 - mscomm.Output(char(0)) ---> give '' space .

Similarly for  7  c#--> gives '/a' as character

vb 6.0 --> gives as . black dot

Anyone can suggest me why this difference occurs in both as ASCII coding is same

Comment: What is char in vb6, I thought the keywords were chr and chrw in vb6.  Is char a custom function in your vb6 code?  If so show that code.

Comment: `'/0' ` ? Some code that is close to compilable would help with understanding the problem.

Comment: Try `(char)0` or `(char)a`, you are not comparing apples to apples.

Comment: `vbNullChar` is a prefined constant you should be using.  But your C# snippet sends a "/" and then a "0" so of course that's the result you would get.  As hinted at above you probably meant to use `\0` the escaped NUL character in high-obscurity languages like C#.

Answer (score -1):

VB6 codes everything in ANSI, this is the reason why you're getting question marks and unexpected characters.

Comment: Ya , yup u r right  so i used  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr for converstion in c# .But from 0 to 10  decimal value it gives me difference between both c# and vb 6.0 . After 10 they give me same char output.  Can u show me an example of similar converstion in c# and vb 6.0 for 0 decimal or 7 decimal   . Thanks in advance